# Почему в таблице заголовки дублируются на все строки HTML, Django

Tags: html, django, bootstrap

Прописала заголовок для таблицы, а он дублируется на все строки. В чём может быть причина? Использую Bootstrap.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-hover">
    {% for post in posts%}
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Type of research</th>
            <th>Drug</th>
            <th>Dosage</th>
            <th>Journal</th>
            <th>Article</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            {% for art in post.fk_article_research.all%}
            <td>{{art.fk_type_of_research}}</td>
            <td>{{art.fk_drug}}</td>
            <td>{{art.dosage}}</td>
            <td>{{art.fk_journal}}</td>
            <td>{% for author in post.fk_author.all %}{{author.name}} 
{%endfor%}</td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'post_single' pk=post.id %}">{{post.name}}</a> 
</td>
            {%endfor%}
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    {% endfor %}
</table>

{#<a href="{% url 'post_single' pk=post.fk_article %}">{{post.fk_article}}</a>#}
</div>
</div>
        </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой у вас заголовок дублируется?

Comment: как прописали так и работает.
`{% for post in posts%}<thead>`

Comment: Перенесите `    {% for post in posts%}` после `<tbody>`. Вы просто делаете цикл по thead.

Comment: Помогло, спасибо!